# What is oracle error code for table locks?

Tags: oracle, error-handling, locking, blocking

I need send to client valid error messages from my app, and I must send messages for tables locks, what is oracle error codes for table blocked/locked error? (something like ORA-000123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-00054 Resource busy

I believe this is what you want.

Per request:

oerr command (DOS & UNIX):
oerr -h
Usage: oerr facility error

Facility is identified by the prefix string in the error message.
For example, if you get ORA-7300, "ora" is the facility and "7300"
is the error.  So you should type "oerr ora 7300".

Comment: Is it there a table of codes? Could be good to add it to your answer so it is more useful.

Comment: There is a command you can run in DOS or linux: oerr    See above